# Passing parameters to an Inno Setup Check function from multiple entries

Tags: inno-setup

I have many `[components]` and I'd like to write only **one** function to check for their specific registry keys. I can write one function for each entry, but I'd like to sum them up within one function. Any ideas? :)

Trying to illustrate:

```
[components]  
Name: "MyProgram for A"; (...); Check: CheckRegKey  
Name: "MyProgram for B"; (...); Check: CheckRegKey  
Name: "MyProgram for C"; (...); Check: CheckRegKey  
...  


[code]  
function CheckRegKey: Boolean; 
  begin 
    Result:=RegValueExists(HKLM64, '...', '...')
    //check if A is installed
    //check if B, C,... or a mix of them is installed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not precisely sure if I get your question right, but well, for writing a single [`Check`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm#Check) parameter function for different component entries you will need to have an input parameter by which you will distinguish between those components. In code something like:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Components]
Name: "A"; Description: "MyProgram for A"; Check: CheckRegKey(1)
Name: "B"; Description: "MyProgram for B"; Check: CheckRegKey(2)
Name: "C"; Description: "MyProgram for C"; Check: CheckRegKey(3)

[Code]
function CheckRegKey(CompType: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  case CompType of
    1: Result := RegValueExists(...);
    2: Result := RegValueExists(...);
    3: Result := RegValueExists(...);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Oh, okay I will use it in the future (I'm new here).