# How to control addition of file in Inno Setup 6 script using the presence of a substring in a defined string

Tags: inno-setup

I have two executables which do the same thing, but one is built to target a DEV environment, and the other a PROD environment.

```
my-app-dev.exe
my-app-prod.exe
```

A VERSION parameter is always passed into the Inno build script which contains the build version in one of the following two formats:

```
"1.0.0"
"1.0.0-DEV"
```

In the `[Files]` section, how can I include the **my-app-dev.exe** if the current value of VERSION contains the **DEV** suffix, but include the **my-app-prod.exe** if not?

I figured a `Check` parameter would be the way to resolve this, but I can't even get the simplest case to work.

For example, the following adds the file to the build despite the `Check` function clearly returning `False`.

```
[Files]
Source: "my-app-dev.exe"; DestDir: {app}; Check: ShouldIncludeDev

function ShouldIncludeDev: Boolean;
begin
    Result := False;
end;
```

Perhaps I must be missing something fundamental here...

Comment: I think that you have to test the parameter `{param:xxx}` and examine what the value is. If it is xyz, then return true, else return false. Etc. Others may be able to offer better idea.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149410/passing-parameters-to-an-inno-setup-check-function-from-multiple-entries

Comment: So perhaps: `Check: ShouldIncludeDev({param:xxx})`. Then inyour function test the value of that param and return accordingly. Not tested.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and all sorts of other attempts at a solution, but nothing was appearing to work. However it has become apparent to me that the Check functions in the [Files] section will correctly control files being installed, but all files, regardless of the Check function will get compressed and compiled into the installer for some reason. So watching it compile I was seeing both binaries getting compressed and compiled, but actually running the installer only installed the expected binary.

Comment: This behaviour actually makes sense because the Check function might yeild a different result on different machines so all files need to be compiled. I think what would work better in my case was having an optional command line define for "IS_DEV_BUILD" or something, and then to wrap the dev exe entry in the [Files] section in an #ifdef clause.

Comment: You could do that (I think). But I know others are more knowledgeable about using the pre-processor. Actually - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429104/2287576. I think that could help. Looks like your "param" becomes a #define so you can just test for existence and put your data in it. If I am on the right path I could knock up an answer for you.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this answer ([Inno Setup IDE and ISCC/ISPP passing define](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13423317/2287576)) you could do this:

1. Pass the value via command line parameter:

   ```
   /DargDEV="DEV"
   ```
2. In your `[Files]` section you can then do this:

   ```
   #ifdef argDEV
       Source: "my-app-dev.exe"; DestDir: {app};
   #else
       Source: "my-app-prod.exe"; DestDir: {app};
   #endif
   ```

---

#### Notes

It uses the [`#ifdef`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_ifdef.htm) pre-processor directive.

Comment: If OP wants to stick to the `/DVERSION=1.0.0-DEV` as asked for in the question, the condition can be changed to `#if Pos(VERSION, "-DEV") > 0`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for the clarification. I missed that.